# How do generate a equally time spaced between meetings using userform

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how can I go about generating an equal time-space between meetings on worksheet after inputting the "number of meetings", "start time" and "end time" (image shown below). Upon inputting the information into the userform, the "generate" button would then list out all meetings between the indicated "start time" and "end time".

For example, if there are 5 meeting and the start time is 12:00 and end time is 17:00. The generate button would show 5 meetings all space 1 hour apart. 1 meeting would be at 12pm, 1 meeting would be 1pm and so on...

[image]

CURRENT CODE

Currently, I am calculating the time difference between Start and End time and calculate the available time for each meetings. How I do not know how to display all  5 meetings where they are equally space apart.

```
Private Sub generate_btn_Click()
    totalHour = DateDiff("n", startTime, endTime) / 60
    timePer = num_observation / totalHour


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to use `TimeValue` to parse string with time as proper time and then all calculations become easy:

```
Sub CalculateHours(numberOfMeetings As String, startTime As String, endTime As String)
    startHour = TimeValue(startTime)
    endHour = TimeValue(endTime)

    differenceTime = endHour - startHour
    meetingDuration = differenceTime / numberOfMeetings

    For i = 1 To numberOfMeetings
        Cells(i, 1) = startHour + meetingDuration * (i - 1)
    Next
End Sub

Sub Test()
    ' Here's how you call it, the parameters will come from your form
    Call CalculateHours(5, "12:00", "14:00")
End Sub
```

And the output is:

[image]